# Finding dominating function of $ f(x)=ab^2\frac{\exp(-b^2x^2−a^2b^2/x^2)}{x^2}. $

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $b$ be a constant, I want to find majorant of this function on $[0,\infty)$, which does not depend on $a$.

Let $$ f(x)=ab^2\frac{\exp(-b^2x^2−a^2b^2/x^2)}{x^2}.     $$

I want to find a function $g(x)$ ($a$ is variable, and $g(x)$ does not depend on $a$), which satisfies $g(x)≧f(x)$,and

$$\int_0^\infty g(x)\;\mathbb{d}x<∞$$

I tried many attempts to eliminate $a$, like seeing $f(x)$ as function of a , but all in vain.This may take a flexible idea.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at $f$ as a function of $a$ and find its maximum. That would be it.

Comment: I tried, but the maximal is not integrable.

Comment: Too bad! This means you want to have your cake, and eat it too. Any bigger function won't be integrable either. Any smaller function won't be a majorant.

Comment: Then, how can we justify d/da∮[0,∞）e^（-b^2x^2-a^2b^2/x^2）/x^2＝ ∮[0,∞）d/da e^（-b^2x^2-a^2b^2/x^2）/x^2 dx  ？　This is a true proposition which should be justified, and I have no other way other than checking the title question.

Comment: Well, it seems that you want uniform convergence of some sort or another. You don't have it. But that doesn't mean you don't have your derivative.

Comment: Try Cauchy-Schlomilch transformation.